# Change layout and save state in DialogFragment on configuration changed

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, savestate

I have a DialogFragment which holds custom AlertDialog with a custom view.

And there is a problem, on orientation change. It's needed:

1. Save dialog state (state of views in custom view in AlertDialog) if needed.
2. Change the alert dialog's layout and its size;

When activity is recreating on rotate everything is fine, it's enough to implement `AlertDialog.onSaveInstanceState()` and `AlertDialog.onRestoreInstanceState()` and DialogFragment will do the rest.

*The problem is when activity is **NOT** recreating on orientation change, but it's still needed to do two steps described above.* The perfect solution will be to encapsulate that logic inside of derived AlertDialog or DialogFragment, so the users who will use that dialog will not worry for anything.

---

What I've tried so far.

1. Easy way. Do not recreate the dialog.

We can figure out that orientation was changed either implementing `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener()` in our AlertDialog or in `DialogFragment.onConfigurationChanged()`. At this moment, I was trying to save state, reinflate view and call `AlertDialog.setView()`. It's not working. The state is saving, dialog size is changing, but the view is remaining the old view. I don't know why, maybe it's not allowed to reinflate the view when the dialog is showing.

2. Dismiss dialog, recreate, show again.

I was trying to do something like that. In DialogFragment:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    dismiss();
    show(getFragmentManager(), getTag());
}
```

So hide, recreate dialog, show again. *And it works!*

But. If I:

1. Open dialog
2. Go to the home screen (hide application)
3. `onSaveInstanceState` method of Activity and DialogFragment is called.
4. Rotate device
5. Restore application
6. `DialogFragment.onConfigurationChanged()` will be called and if I try to call here `dismiss()` or `show()` this time, I'll receive `"Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState"` because at this moment activity is not actually restored.

And I don't see the right place to do something like that.

---

**So, any other things to try?**

Comment: What is reason that you use `configChanges = orientation` for your activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand your problem, you want to have different layout for landscape/portrait orientations?
If yes, and your activity is not recreating because of manifest `configChanges = orientation` you have `onConfigurationChanged` callback to handle anything i.e. your layout changes.

While creating your custom dialog, you probably are using `setContentView(View view)`.

So while creating your dialog for the first time set some content view which is only general container like `FrameLayout` etc.

Then create method which is inflating your internal layout with all content that you want ot show and add it dynamically to your container `FrameLayout`. When orientation changes... remove internal layout, inflate it once again with different orientation and add once again.

Comment: You are right about why it's not recreating. Currently, I'm not using `setContentView(View view)` because I'm using custom `AlertDialog` which is creating in `DialogFragment.createDialog()`, so `DialogFragment` is acting only like a wrapper around `AlertDialog` to handle saving state, all logic is inside `AlertDialog`. But I will try you suggestion and will try to use `setContentView(View view)` instead of using `AlertDialog`.

Comment: But if you are using custom AleryDialog how you are setting it's custom layout?

Comment: Now I'm inflating view inside derived `AlertDialog` class and calling `AlertDialog.setView()` on initialization stage. Then on rotation I was trying to do the same (reinflate view and call `AlertDialog.setView()` again). I'll try not to call `AlertDialog.setView()` again but remove children and reinflate my content to existing container, thanks!